# How to buy space on server and use it for storing and retrieving data in android?

Tags: android, save, server, data-retrieval

M completely new to android. I have developed a basic app which takes user details and save it. And later use it for login. I want to know how to buy server space and how to save and retrieve data from it. Kindly provide some code snippets/ tutorial/links to help me with it.

Comment: Are you sure you want to buy a server?  Or create your own REST/data manipulation endpoints?  Learn SQL/NoSQL? That is not the only solution, although it is one.  I'd suggest https://www.parse.com/ integration with your Android app.  It's simple and shields you from all the intricacies of data maintenance.  Google App Engine (GAE) would also be a good place to host a web service stack, but you're asking for full stack development resources.

Answer (score 1):

If your are new Parse is definitely the answer. It's very easy to integrate in Android and save's you the trouble of learning sql and php or whatever.

https://parse.com/

https://parse.com/docs/android_guide - link to the Android Guide

Answer (score 0):

questions like what to buy are not allowed with that said.  Simply use the google plus login button https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in

Or

The accounts on the device are free to use and don't require a server to use.

Bits to get a user email from the device.  Typically you would persist the email locally on the device.  Notes:  Create a fragment so code can run from any fragment.

```
private void get_UserEmail() {
    if (view == null) {
        return;
    }
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvApplicationUserName))
            .setText("Searching device for user accounts...");

    final FragmentManager fragManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

    Fragment f = new Fragment() {
        @Override
        public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
            super.onAttach(activity);
            startActivityForResult(AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
                    new String[]{"com.google"}, false, null, null, null, null), REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                     Intent data) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT) {
                String mEmail = "";
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    if (data.hasExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME)) {
                        mEmail = data
                                .getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                    }
                }
                if (mEmail != null) {
                    doSomethingWithEmail(mEmail);
                }
            }
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            fragManager.beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();
        }
    };
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragManager
            .beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(f, "xx"
            + REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

You can authenticate the google accounts with the GoogleAuthUtil.  There's a bit more to it than this but if you get a non null for ret the account is signed in and you have access to whatever was specified in tokenScope.

```
   ret = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(mActivity, mEmail, tokenScope);
```